# username regex quantifier (length) - can't manage to make it work properly

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to validate a username by the following rules:

1 - total length of the string must be between 5 and 12 characters

2 - it must start with at least one alphabetic character [a-zA-Z]

3 - after that, it can contain any alphanumeric characters AND maximum one of : [_-.]

4 - it can't end with one of: [_-.], it can only end with at least one alphanumeric 
character

Here is the regex I am working on:
^(([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]+[-._]??)+([a-zA-Z0-9])){5,12}$

Here are the problems:

a) it only validates if the string is at least 15 characters long (even though I have {5,12}

b) it doesn't validate if the string contains one of [_-.] as the second character

c) a string like "aaa-a-a-aaaaaaaaaa" validates even though it has more than one of [*-.]
Actually, the more alphanumeric characters I have in the string, the more repetitions of [*-.] it allows (at least it screams if they're adjacent to one another)

d) if after a digit I write a letter and then one of [_-.] - it doesn't validate

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this one:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=[^_.-]*[_.-]?[^_.-]*$)[\w.-]{3,10}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Using positive lookahead(`(?=[^_.-]*[_.-]?[^_.-]*$)`) its checking if there is maximum one of `[_-.]` in string.